# how to call a method with -- at runtime in python (like shell script) with run time arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, arguments, runtime

how to call a method with -- at runtime  in python (like shell script) with run time arguments 
for example below file name is mathematics.py

```
class maths():
    pass

    def add(self, *args):
        sum = 0
        for x in args:
            sum = sum + x
        return sum

    def mult(self, *args):
        if args:
            mul = 1
            for x in args:
                mul = mul * x
            return mul
        else:
            return None
m = maths()
m.add(1,2,3,)
m.mult(1,2,3)
```

i would like to run this as :

```
python mathematics.py --add 1 2 3
or 
python mathematics.py --mult 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

use 'optionParser' or 'sys' module

```
from optparse import OptionParser
parser = OptionParser()
parser.add_option('-m', "--mult",dest='mult' default='true')

(options, _args) = parser.parse_args()
```

options.mult is your arguments

```py
import sys
a1 = sys.argv[0]
a2 = sys.argv[1]
a3 = sys.argv[2]
```

a1 is your file name,
a2 is your first argument,
a2 is your second argument,

your arguments:python app.py port 8888

a1=app.py

a2=port

a3=8888

Comment: could you please share how to do it uising sys module ?